# Disable override warning C++

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, warnings

I'm compiling my c++ project with the flag -std=c++11 because I use override in one of my classes, even so I'm getting this warning:

```
warning: override controls (override/final) only available with -
std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

I would like to know how to disable this warning or I would appreciate if you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You should investigate why you get that warning rather than disabling it.

Comment: Apparently you are not using `-std=c++11`. This commonly happens when you use an IDE where you specified an extra compiler flag `-std=c++11` but later on it gets overridden by a different "standard selection setting". You can probably find the command line argument to invoke the compiler somewhere and check.

Comment: Are you *sure* there are not multiple "-std=" options specified? What does the *actual* commandline look like when running the compiler?

Comment: It looks like this  ' g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp class1.cpp class2.cpp class3.cpp -o main '

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that warning can be separately disabled.

Instead of disabling the warning, I recommend that you fix the bug. Your code uses a language feature that was introduced in C++11, but you compile with an earlier standard enabled. You have two options:

- Do not use new ("new"; it's been 6 years...) standard features that are not supported by the the standard (and the compiler) that you use.
- Compile with new standard version enabled, using a compiler that supports that standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable warning with pragma

```
#pragma warning( disable : _WARNING_NUMBER_)
```

Where _WARNING_NUMBER_ is number of your warning

However, you should always listen to your compiler and fix the warning instead of disabling